# Set Error message From Login Module in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, authentication

I have created my own Login Module implementing `javax.security.api.LoginModule` and I have two types of errors: *wrong password* and *password entered after expired time*.

How can I show the specific error message on the login-error page in my web app, rather than something generic like "login failed"?